# AngularJS Excel File Format or file extension is not valid Error

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am trying to download an xlsx file from an HttpResponseMessage returned from the api, but I am getting an error when opening the xlsx file after it downloads.

The error: Excel cannot open the file 'filename' because the file format or file extension is not valid.

My AngularJS code

```
        public downloadFile(url: string): ng.IPromise<any> {
            return fetch(url).then((data => {
                let filename: string = this.getFileName(data);
                let binaryData = [];
                binaryData.push(data);
                let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }));
                downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
            }));            
        }
```

My C# code:

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaTypeHeader);
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        return response;
```

Comment: Can you open the xlxs as a zip file (change the extension to `.zip` and try opening it)? If so, can you open it with the _OpenXML Productivity Tool_ (available from GitHub)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS Code:

```
public downloadFile(url: string): ng.IPromise<any> {
return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
        let filename: string = 'file.xlsx'; // Change this to your desired file name
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink); // Clean up after download
    });
}
```

C# Code:

the Content-Type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" which may not be appropriate for an xlsx file. You might need to set it to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" which is the appropriate MIME type for xlsx files.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
return response;
```

Comment: Making the changes you suggested in the Angular side fixed my issue. I did not have to change the backend though. I appreciate your help! You saved me hours of headache.